# An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details - Entity Framework error

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework for some the bulk operations on the database.

A CSV file will be uploaded by the application which can be of any number of rows and columns, application uploaded the file on server and create a transaction for database insertion. We have used transaction to avoid data garbage, if any corrupt data found we rollback the complete operation.

My question is that when I am using smaller files with less number of data then it runs perfectly.

Using large file I have received this error in the error log

> 2012-04-06 12:28:13 PM [ 4] Amit-PC [fe80::4c0c:23b9:4c3:bbb8%10]
>   ERROR VC.Phoenix.QM.Web.UI.Controllers.QuotasController - An
>   application Error has occured in method: ProcessMatrix(). Please
>   contact application administrator. Error detail is : An error occurred
>   while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
>   details.
>
> stackTrace
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult[TElement](EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, EntitySet entitySet, EdmType edmType, MergeOption
>   mergeOption)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String
>   functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String
>   functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>   at VC.Phoenix.QM.EntityDataModel.QuotaManagementContainer.SetTotalColumns(Nullable`1
>   quotaId) in
>   D:\OptimusRepository\VisionCritical\PhoenixQuota\Branches\BugFixes\VC.Phoenix.QM.EntityDataModel\QuotaManagement1.Designer.cs:line
>   317
>   at VC.Phoenix.QM.Web.UI.Controllers.QuotasController.SetTotalColumnData(Int32
>   quotaId, QuotaManagementContainer quotaManagementContext) in
>   D:\OptimusRepository\VisionCritical\PhoenixQuota\Branches\BugFixes\VC.Phoenix.QM.Web.UI\Controllers\QuotasController.cs:line 3032
>   at VC.Phoenix.QM.Web.UI.Controllers.QuotasController.ProcessMatrix(Int32
>   quotaId, String isCount, String cellPos) in
>   D:\OptimusRepository\VisionCritical\PhoenixQuota\Branches\BugFixes\VC.Phoenix.QM.Web.UI\Controllers\QuotasController.cs:line 844

Please help me to understand the issue with Entity framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will certainly understand that it's gonna be hard to understand the exception if we don't have the code in 
QuotasController.cs line 844...
And in QuotasController.SetTotalColumnData, lin 3032
StackTrace is fine, but not alone ;)

Comment: And the inner exception.